# A simple nested SQL statement

Tags: sql

I have a question in SQL that I am trying to solve. I know that the answer is very simple but I just can not get it right. I have two tables, one with customers and the other one with orders. The two tables are connected using customer_id. The question is to list all the customers that did not make any order! The question is to be run in MapInfo Professional, a GIS desktop software, so not every SQL command is applicable to that program. In other words, I will be thankful if I get more than approach to solve that problem.

Here is how I have been thinking:

```
SELECT customer_id 
from customers
WHERE order_id not in (select order_id from order) 
   and customer.customer_id = order.customer_id
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about this:

```
SELECT * from customers
WHERE customer_id not in (select customer_id from order)
```

The logic is, if we don't have a customer_id in order that means that customer has never placed an order. As you have mentioned that customer_id is the common key, hence above query should fetch the desired result.

Comment: It worked! That makes sense. I knew the answer would be simple.

Thank you so much for your help!

Comment: I can not upvote the answer because I have a reputation of 1! I wish I can accept the answer and mark the question as answered!

Comment: @Latvian You cannot upvote but you should surely be able to Accept

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT c.customer_id 
FROM customers c
LEFT JOIN orders o ON (o.customer_id = c.customer_id)
WHERE o.order_id IS NULL
```

Answer (score 0):

... The NOT EXISITS way:

```
SELECT * FROM customers
WHERE NOT EXISTS ( 
  SELECT * FROM orders
  WHERE orders.customer_id = customer.customer_id
)
```

Answer (score 0):

There are some problems with your approach:

1. There is probably no order_id in the customers table, but in your where-statement you refer to it
2. The alias (or table-name) order in the where-statement (order.customer_id) is not known because there is no join statement in there
3. If there would be a join, you would filter out all customers without orders, exactly the opposite of what you want

Your question is difficualt to answer to me because I do not know which SQL subset MapInfo GIS understands, but lets try:

```
select * from customers c where not exists (select * from order o where o.customer_id=c.customer_id)
```